# Cannot coerce class to a data.frame

Tags: raster, r, data-frame, random-forest

I'm using R to run a random forest to predict the distribution of sediment classes in a study area. I have a .csv of the locations where sediment has been sampled, and rasters of all my predictor variables.

```
bbpi <- raster("broadbpi_st.tif")
east <- raster("eastness.tif")
fbpi <- raster("finebpi_st.tif")
bath <- raster("gebco_bathymetry.tif")
north <- raster("northness.tif")
curd <- extractByMask(raster("current_direction.tif"), msk= bath, spatial = TRUE)
curm <- extractByMask(raster("current_magnitude.tif"), msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
#rug <- raster("rugosity.tif")
slope <- extractByMask(raster("slope_final.tif"), msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
area <- extractByMask(raster("surface_planar_arearatio.tif"), msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
umean <- extractByMask(raster("ustar_mean.tif"),msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
umax <- extractByMask(raster("ustarmax_IDW.tif"),msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
wmax <- extractByMask(raster("wavepower_max_IDW.tif"),msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
wmean <- extractByMask(raster("wavepower_mean.tif"),msk=bath, spatial=TRUE)
rfstack <- stack(bbpi,fbpi,bath,east,north,curd,curm,slope,area,umean,umax,wmax,wmean)
names(rfstack) <- c("bbpi","fbpi","bath","east","north","curd","curm","slope","area","umean","umax","wmax","wmean")

points <- read.csv("bottomgrabs.csv")
set.seed(321)
rf1 <- randomForest(factor(DEPOT_GRO) ~ ., data=points, ntree=500, mtry=10, na.action=na.omit)

test1 <- raster::predict(rf1,newdata=rfstack,type="prob")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(newdata) :
> cannot coerce class ‘structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")’ to a data.frame

How do I fix this and make my random forest run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get this to run by converting the raster stack yourself. For example, I've replicated your error with a trivial test data set:

```
> raster::predict(rf1, newdata=rstack)
Error in as.data.frame.default(newdata) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")’ to a data.frame
```

and this runs:

```
> raster::predict(rf1, newdata=as.data.frame(rstack))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 B  C  C  C  A  A  A  A  C  A  A  A  C  B  A  A 
Levels: A B C
```

Comment: The solution you gave returns a different error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'ï..OID_' not found

Comment: That's probably a column in your fitted data (the CSV) that you don't have new data for (in the form of the name of a layer in your raster stack). Can't really debug that without all of your data sets, or more info about what you do have. I think my answer fixes the the initial problem so you should mark this as correct, then see if you can fix the subsequent error, and if not then post a new question.

Comment: yes, I fixed the follow up error. Thank you for your help!